# National Instruments Measurement Studio example of VB.NET for analog (v) input & output

Tags: .net, vb.net, nidaqmx, measurement-studio

Is there a Meas. Studio example for a VB.NET app for inputting and outputting analog values at an NI USB-6343 DAQ?

Details:
My 6343 has A31&A32 controlling voltage to a LED (THOR LABS LEDD1B),  and then A1&A3 inputting voltage from a photo diode (ThorLabs PDA36A).

Using VS2013Pro

Answer (score 0):

There are examples for VB.NET that include *both* [analog input and analog output](http://www.ni.com/example/6999/en/#C.NETandVisualBasic.NETVB.NET): *Synchronization :: Synchronize Analog Input and Analog Output - Digital Start*.

The DAQmx driver installs examples in the [public user's Documents folder](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/E3BAF6FC4017960B8625755A00525D37#vb6).